# Dreamhost Rack woes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, dreamhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Phusion Passenger Error: You have activated rack 1.2.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774621/phusion-passenger-error-you-have-activated-rack-1-2-1-but-your-gemfile-requires)

I have a Rails 3.0.6 application running on dreamhost. Sometimes I get this passenger error:

> You have already activated rack 1.2.1,
>   but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.3.
>   Consider using bundle exec.

However, in 90% of the cases the app is just working fine! And when I refresh, it *always* works fine, for the next consequent x requests (regardless of the value of x).

So it looks like if no one touches the app for a certain time, this error is produced, then it doesn't show up until the app is left dormant for some time again...

I am not sure this makes sense but this is what I am experiencing after 2 weeks of monitoring the app...

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue... any luck on what's wrong?